# \lstlistoflistings doesn't have enough room between numbers and title

Tags: listings

I'm using the \lstlistoflistings command from the listings package to generate my list of code samples. Unfortunately there isn't enough room between the number and the code listing title. See the example image, it should read 13.10.1 on that last line. How do I adjust the column width?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Instead of `3em` in the third argument, use the lenght that best suits your needs (in the original definition the value is `2.3em`).

A complete example:

The default layout:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\setcounter{chapter}{13}
\chapter{Test}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{13}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A]
A
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And now with the distance increased:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\setcounter{chapter}{13}
\chapter{Test}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{13}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=A]
A
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps to maintain consistency in the other lists, you could also think about redefining `\l@figure`, `\l@table`,... if necessary (or using a dedicated package to change the distance between the label and the titles).